# How can I return a promise from my ActionCreator in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following handler that dispatches two actions...

```
 _onPress = () => {
    let { request,userId} = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(acceptRequest(request.id,userId))
    this.props.dispatch(navigatePop());
 }
```

What I would like this to look like instead is the following...

```
 _onPress = () => {
    let { request,userId} = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(acceptRequest(request.id,userId))
      .then(this.props.dispatch(navigatePop()))
 }
```

My ActionCreator looks like this...

```
 export function acceptRequest(requestId,fulfilledBy){
   return dispatch => {
     fulfillments.create(requestId,fulfilledBy)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(fulfillment => {
         dispatch(_acceptRequestSuccess(fulfillment))
       })
       .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         dispatch(_acceptRequestError(error))
       })
   }
 }
```

I am aware that they have many middleware(s) that people suggest, but I don't
see how any of them fit this scenario unless I am completed doing somthing
incorrectly.

In my particular case, I only want to dispatch the seond action if the first is
successful, but I don't want to do this from the action creator because then
it is less reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I misunderstood you, you should mention that you are using redux-thunk.

I don't think redux action should return a promise, I think you should do everything in the component and then play with the promise, like this:

```
_onPress = () => {
    let { request,userId} = this.props;

    fulfillments.create(requestId,fulfilledBy)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(fulfillment => {
            this.props.dispatch(_acceptRequestSuccess(fulfillment))
       })
       .then(() => {
            this.props.dispatch(navigatePop());
       })
       .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         this.props.dispatch(_acceptRequestError(error))
       })
 }
```

But if you still want to return a promise you can make the function inside the action return the promise:

```
export function acceptRequest(requestId,fulfilledBy){
   return dispatch => {
     return fulfillments.create(requestId,fulfilledBy)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(fulfillment => {
         dispatch(_acceptRequestSuccess(fulfillment))
       })
       .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         dispatch(_acceptRequestError(error))
       })
   }
 }
```